# Use mongodb document to match a search

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection of documents. I field in the document is a Regex.
I want to take an input string from the user &
I want the Regex from the MongoDB to match the given string and echo out that resulting document.
eg:

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "5eeeef2a132cb8992da8"
    },
    "type": "integer",
    "regex": "\d+",
    "example": "12345"
}
```

If someone now inputs a string like 776847, it should go back to the collection compare the regex with the string and echo out integer, etc...

Any best methods to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If if understood you you mean that if the user input is : "1234"

and your mongo db is like :

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "5eeeef2a132cb8992da8"
    },
    "type": "integer",
    "regex": "\d+",
    "example": "12345"
}
```

The result will be integer.

you can extract all the mongo data and loop it

or

you can use mongo find method with mongodb cursor

example:
its in python but you will get the general idea

```
def func():
   search = collection.find({'example':<user input>})
   if search:
      result = re.search(search['regex'],<user input>)
      if result != []:
         return = search['type']
      else:
         return "No match"
```

Hope it will help you

B.R

Shlomy